# Generating several random double numbers in java

Tags: java, math, random, double, coordinates

Every time when I try to generate random coordinates of city in this way,

```
public City () {                    
        super();
        this.x = Math.random()*200;
        this.y = Math.random()*200;
    }
```

I get the same values for the X and Y, which means that all cities are on same line on map. My question is how to avoid this? How to create different coordinates? Thanks.

Comment: What is x, what is y? What types are they?

Comment: You need to give us a self sufficient code allowing us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do mean suppose you generated 10 instance of `city` do all 10 `city` have same `x` and `y`?

Comment: you need to create parameterized constructor and pass two variables.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed a class like this:

```
class City {
  private double x;
  private double y;

  public City() {
    super();
    this.x = Math.random() * 200;
    this.y = Math.random() * 200;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "City [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
  }
}
```

When I create new City objects I get (as it should be expected by the Math API) different values:

```
City [x=10.552289272723247, y=28.548756787475504]
City [x=58.96588997141927, y=146.87205149574288]
City [x=186.69728798772306, y=179.3787764147533]
```

Don't get me wrong - maybe at the point where you check the values you use by mistake twice the same?

Answer (score 1):

To get different double values use `java.util.Random` class. Below, there's an example, it prints four different double values:

```
   java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();

    System.out.println(random.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(random.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(random.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(random.nextDouble());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Random`.
Example:

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(11); // from 0 to 10
double y = random.nextDouble(); // from 0 to 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do wrong something else which is not in question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = Math.random() * 200;
        double y = Math.random() * 200;
        System.out.println(x + ":"+y);
}
```

consider above code snap and you will get different x and y values..!

Please make sure that you are using **new** keyword every time while creating object of city.